# Can you multiply words in python?

Tags: python, string, nlp

I've been going through the old Columbia NLP class on Coursera and I'm currently trying to do the first assignment. The class uses Python but since I'm more comfortable with Java/Groovy I decided to rewrite all of the helper scrips that were given in the first assignment in Groovy.

I noticed that the original author does something that looks like multiplication. The specific function that I'm talking about is below:

```
def get_ngrams(sent_iterator, n):
"""
Get a generator that returns n-grams over the entire corpus,
respecting sentence boundaries and inserting boundary tokens.
Sent_iterator is a generator object whose elements are lists
of tokens.
"""
for sent in sent_iterator:
     #Add boundary symbols to the sentence
     w_boundary = (n-1) * [(None, "*")]
     w_boundary.extend(sent)
     w_boundary.append((None, "STOP"))
     #Then extract n-grams
     ngrams = (tuple(w_boundary[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(w_boundary)-n+1))
     for n_gram in ngrams: #Return one n-gram at a time
        yield n_gram
```

Specifically I don't understand this line

```
         w_boundary = (n-1) * [(None, "*")]
```

I see that n is declared in the function definition but I don't really know what it is. Searching for "string multiplication python" doesn't really give me anything helpful. Can somebody explain this python feature or give me a better idea of what I should at least try to search for?

Comment: That is list multiplication. Why not just try it in the interpreter? `n` is an integer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't even think of that. Haha. You wouldn't try Java at the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> w = n * [(None, "*")]
>>> print w
[(None, '*'), (None, '*'), (None, '*')]
```

Comment: That's not a set, and it doesn't actually get replicated; all list elements are actually the same tuple, rather than copies of each other.

Comment: Is None like null? I noticed that it isn't a string.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right. My terminology and understanding is wrong. I removed the offending sentence and am reading up on it. I'll just leave the interpreter output for now.

Comment: So this makes w a list? Nevermind, I found it https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html.